# Getting ListView item click position outside of getView() method

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` that look like this :

[image]

..and I've been using this code to handle incoming click events to start/stop the music playback :

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

...

previewBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    boolean isToggled = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
                    Mp3File music = getItem(position);

                    if (!isToggled) {
                        callbackActivity.onMusicPreviewStopped();
                        ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(false);
                    } else {
                        callbackActivity.onMusicPreviewRequested(music);
                    }
                }
            });
...
```

Which works perfectly fine TBH. But I have this habit of making the class implements the required interface instead of creating a new one for every view created.

It'd be pretty straight-forward *if* I choose to ignore the `position` of the item clicked. Sadly, I need the `position` to correctly identify which `Mp3File` is playing and to stop it.

Could you give me some suggestions on how I could make it work?

..or is this the only way of doing it?

Comment: use onitenclicklistener of listview in activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head I'd suggest to set position as the button tag. Then implement onClick once for the class and use `v.getTag()` to retrieve the position of the button

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

...
previewBtn.setTag(position);
...


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean isToggled = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
                Mp3File music = getItem(view.getTag());

                if (!isToggled) {
                    callbackActivity.onMusicPreviewStopped();
                    ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    callbackActivity.onMusicPreviewRequested(music);
                }
            }
```

Comment: It worked! Even better - I set the relevant `Mp3File` as the tag instead of its `position` and just call `view.getTag()` to retrieve it. I've never known item tags could be this useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should use one OnClickListener (defined in your adapter class) and use it on every preview button. Currently you are creating a new OnClickListener every time getView() is called, and that's wasteful.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been trying to do but I need the position supplied by `getView` to send it as a parameter to another method. What @carlosjimenez did was to show me to assign the `position` as a tag so that whenever the `onClick` for that button is called, I could easily get its `position` by calling the `view.getTag()` method.